# Connection points on lifeline not evenly distributed

Tags: connection, line, actor, visio, points

I am trying to create a very basic communication sequence diagram in Visio 2013, but the connection points on lifelines are not evenly distrbuted, making it impossible to create a nice looking diagram. Acoording to many examples found on the Internet, the points should be evenly distributed. I just installed Visio, so it is a fresh installation.

Does anybody know what causes this or how to fix this?

I cannot include a picture because of my reputation (just started here), so here it is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4erj.jpg

Comment: Similar issue occurs on Visio 2016.

Comment: Some problem encountered in Visio 2016, any solutions?